# This node js code doenot result anything

Tags: node.js

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http');
});
server.listen(8080);

I am not getting result for the above nodejs code i am executing the code like this node hw.js from git bash 
I am new to nodejs

Comment: where to intall the npm install http

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating an HTTP server on port 8080.

For every request it will respond with `'Hello Http'`

Try opening http://localhost:8080/ in your browser and you will see it.

Comment: this is the correct answer, 

is there any error after run node?

Comment: It seems like something else is listening on port 8080. Try changing port number in your code to another one, e.g. `8084`

Comment: var http_service = require('http');

http_service.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
    console.log("Hello");
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server running on port 8080.');
console.log("test"); i did run this code i can find the console log messages outside create server function live server running on 8080 port and test, But  Hello is not printed